# O() notation used in algorithms

Tags: algorithm

Why can't we write 
2n=O(n^2)
While it is ok to write
2n =o(n^2)
Can u make me a little clear regarding of the difference between O() and o()
I tried understanding using the computer algorithm by sahani.
but my doubt is not clear

Comment: `2n` is in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: There are three notations used in computer science to describe asymptotic complexity, namely O-notation, Theta-notation and Omega-notation. 2n is O(n^2) but not Theta(n^2).

Answer (score 6):

small o notation means an upper bound asymptotic complexity, that cannot reach the "maximal asymptotic complexity"

For example, `7n^2` is in `O(n^2)` but is NOT in `o(n^2)`. The complexity markers (O,o,Omega,omega,Theta) are all [sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) of functions, if we use set terminology:

```
o(f(n)) = O(f(n)) \ Theta(f(n))
```

Where, Theta is the usual big Theta notation, and is given in set terminology by:

```
Theta(f(n)) = O(f(n)) [intersection] Omega(f(n))
```

in words, `o(f(n))` contains all the functions that are in `O(f(n))` but NOT in `Theta(f(n))`

---

As a side note, please note that for your example - `f(n) = 2n`, it is both in `O(n^2)` AND `o(n^2)`, but only in `O(n)` - and NOT in `o(n)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also say 2n=O(n^2), there is no problem with it. the definitions are as follow:

```
Big-O Notation : We say f(n) is O(g(n) iff There there exist positive constant c and n0 such that 0 <= f(n) <= c*g(n) for all n >= n0

Small-o Notation : We say f(n) is o(g(n)) iff For any positive constant c, there exists a constant n0 > 0 such that 0 <= f(n) < c*g(n)
```

(Reference for the definitions : Introduction to Algorithm - MIT Press)

Intuitively in small-o notation we have the meaning that f(n) becomes insignificant relative to g(n) as n approaches infinity.

However, about 2n and O(n^2) you can see that by choosing appropriate constants c and n0, based on the definition we have 2n = O(n^2). Simply choose c=1 and n0=3.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple Language to Say ,
o notation gives you information that what maximum time/Space will be required in Worst Case .
Just like sorting and ascending list to descending List .

While O gives you information for Minimum time/space required like already sorted list will require list n comparison to know that list is already sorted !!